# Имитация нажатия мышки CURL + PHP + JS

Tags: php, javascript, парсер, curl

Ребята помогите разобраться с проблемой: 
Суть в чем написал парсер, знаю как вызвать имитацию кнопки через JS теперь не могу это все собрать воедино. Проблемы в том что при POST запросе через CURL должен выполняться JS скрипт который даст номер телефона. 
Пример кода вот он:

```
<?php
header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); // Выставляем правильные 
заголовки чтобы результат был ну русском языке 
include 'phpQuery-onefile.php'; // Подключение библиотеки парсинга;
include 'function.php';  // Подключение основных функций;
$page = 'http://www.job-mo.ru/vac1494107.html';
$url = url_connect($page);
print_r($url); 
?>
```

Файл функции:

```
function url_connect($url){
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$rel = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $rel;
}
```

JS код имитирующий нажатие кнопки:

```
$(document).ready(function(){cp();})
$(document).ready(function(){cm();})
```

Как вызвать данный JS код при загрузке страницы?

Answer (score -1):

**HTML**
где `url: 'http://httpbin.org/html'` - путь к вашему пхп-скрипту, я беру контент с тест-сервиса.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>titile</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {

      $('#parse').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://httpbin.org/html',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html'
          })
          .done(function(e) {
            console.log("success");
            $('#content').html(e);
          })
          .fail(function() {
            console.log("error");
          })
          .always(function() {
            console.log("complete");
          });
      });

    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <input type="button" value="спарсить" id="parse">
  <div id="content">Сюда загрузится контент</div>
</body>

</html>
```

**PHP**

```
header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); // Выставляем правильные 
include 'phpQuery-onefile.php'; // Подключение библиотеки парсинга;
include 'function.php';  // Подключение основных функций;
$page = 'http://www.job-mo.ru/vac1494107.html';
$url = url_connect($page);
print_r($url); 

function url_connect($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $rel = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $rel;
}
```

Comment: Вы уж извините но не могу интерпретировать на свой php код. Сможете объяснить как это работает?

Comment: @ggLike 2 файла всего - хтмл и пхп, хтмл по клику кнопки загружает данные, сформированные пхп.